# How do I set up my Gear VR development environment correctly?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, development-environment, virtual-reality, gear-vr

Question for people developing for Gear VR with a mac: I'm running into some issues setting up my dev environment...

Keep getting compile errors in Unity, when I hit "Play" to preview my project. Here's what I'm using:

Gear VR Innovator Edition for Galaxy S6/Edge
Galaxy S6 running Android 5.1.1
Macbook Pro running OS 10.11.1
Unity 5.2.2f1
Oculus SDK 0.6.2.0
OculusUtilities (for Unity 5 package)

I have Xcode installed, Java: jdk-7u79-macosx-x64, Android SDK: android-sdk_r24.4.1-macosx, oculus runtime 0.5.0.1

Is anything missing? Do I have to go in and tweak the code for the prefabs, because I'm using a new version of Unity?

Comment: What kind of error messages your are getting?

Comment: Update: I've almost got my environment working, after tons of errors, adjusting settings, creating various files, and trying out various versions of thing. I'll write it up here, once I'm sure it works well...